# Pythonically remove the first X words of a string

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do I do it Pythonically?

I know how to delete the first word, but now I need to remove three.

Note that words can be delimited by amount of whitecap, not just a single space (although I could enforce a single white space if it must be so).

---

[Update] I mean any X words; I don't know hat they are.

I am considering looping and repeatedly removing the first word, joining together again, rinsing and repeating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s = "this    is my long     sentence"
print ' '.join(s.split(' ')[3:])
```

This will print

```
"long sentence"
```

Which I think is what you need (it will handle the white spaces the way you wanted).

Answer (score 2):

Try:
    import re

```
print re.sub("(\w+)", "", "a sentence is cool", 3)
```

Prints `cool`

Comment: I don't know what the words are. Sorry, I should have made that clearer. I will update the question.

Comment: This is looking good. Can it handle words separated by white-space?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by simple way as:

```
In [7]: str = 'Hello, this is long string'
In [8]: str = str[3:]
In [9]: str
Out[9]: 'lo, this is long string'
In [10]:
```

Now you can update `3` on line `In[8]` with your `X`

Answer (score 1):

You can use split:

```
>>> x = 3 # number of words to remove from beginning
>>> s = 'word1 word2 word3 word4'
>>> s = " ".join(s.split()) # remove multiple spacing
>>> s = s.split(" ", x)[x] # split and keep elements after index x
>>> s
'word4'
```

This will handle multiple spaces as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the split function to do this. Essentially, it splits the string up into individual (space separated, by default) words. These words are stored in a list and then from that list, you can access the words you want, just like you would with a normal list of other data types. Using the desired words you can then join the list to form a string.

for example:

```
import string

str='This is    a bunch of words'

string_list=string.split(
#The string is now stored in a list that looks like: 
      #['this', 'is', 'a', 'bunch', 'of', 'words']

new_string_list=string_list[3:]
#the list is now: ['bunch', 'of', 'words']

new_string=string.join(new_string_list)
#you now have the string 'bunch of words'
```

You can also do this in fewer lines, if desired (not sure if this is pythonic though)

```
import string as st
str='this is a bunch     of words'
new_string=st.join(st.split(str[3:])
print new_string

#output would be 'bunch of words'
```

Comment: Just realised other people posted the same stuff since I started my answer (and got distracted). Will be happy to delete it if that's what this forum's etiquette suggests; I'm new here so don't know.